# Google App Engine, Eclipse, SDK Not available?

Tags: google-app-engine

Earlier today, I installed the google app engine on eclipse 4.2, following the instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse

I am now trying to install it on a different machine.  However, when I follow step 2, i.e. insert https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2 into the Work With text, I get a problem.

I am told to click the SDK check box, and then "Google App Engine Java SDK".  However, "Google App Engine Java SDK" is no longer under the SDK checkbox, though I'm sure it was before.

I have tried downloading different versions of Eclipse, to see if it's a compatibility issue, but that is not helping.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082268/google-app-engine-sdk-does-not-appear-under-sdks-group-while-installing-it-using).

I finally installed the sdk manually after installing Google's eclipse plugin.

I created a new web application project ("blue g" icon) ->  new web app -> (Google SDK) configure sdks -> add. Then select the unzipped sdk downloaded from here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads?hl=es

Still no answer for the missing downloadable SDK, though.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the help Miguel!  I just retried again this morning, and the SDK has appeared.  I guess the folks at Google must have been doing some sort of update, which made it temporarily unavailable!

Comment: You are right! It is now available. Temporary issue then. Thanks for letting me know, case closed.

Comment: were you able to manually configure the appengine-java-sdk-1.8.5 in eclipse? It still gives the "Failed to initialize" Error.

Answer (score 1):

Google plugin for eclipse Update sites URL's:

Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler)

https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3

Eclipse 3.8/4.2 (Juno)

https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo)

https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7

Answer (score 1):

There was a transient issue during the update of the App Engine SDK that meant the channel was temporarily unavailable for Eclipse users. This has since been resolved, and you should be able to see and update from the channel as before.